# Make div appear with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a div that is hidden and being declared this way:

```
<div id="divLogin" style="visibility:hidden;">
```

My idea is to use jquery to make it slide in

so I created this code:

```
$("btEnviarAcesso").click(function ()
{
    $("divLogin").slideToggle("slow");
});
```

but it is not working... Does someone have any ideia why??

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You are using `visibility:hidden` to hide the `div` but the jQuery show functions don't adjust `visibility`. I would suggest doing this:

```
<div id="divLogin" style="display: none">
```

And then change your code to this:

```
$("#btEnviarAcesso").click(function () {
    $("#divLogin").slideToggle("slow");
});
```

This assumes an element with the ID of `btEnviarAcesso` that can take the `click` event.

**EDIT:** Make sure you put that code inside a `document.ready` function:

```
$(document).ready(function(){ // Or $(function(){ ...
    $("#btEnviarAcesso").click(function () {
        $("#divLogin").slideToggle("slow");
    });
});
```

You can see this solution working in [**this demo**](http://jsbin.com/oloxo).

**Edit 2**

Replace this:

```
<script src="jquery-1.3.2.min.js"/>
<script language="javascript">
```

With this:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
```

Comment: This is probably the issue, not merely just his forgetting to use the id selector. +1!

Comment: @Killercode I updated my answer and added a demo. Check the source of the demo here: http://jsbin.com/oloxo/edit to see where your code might differ from mine. Click "Output" to test how my code works. Does that help?

Comment: I believe that the problem is that I have the div inside a <form id="form1">

May this be the cause???

Comment: It shouldn't be. Can you post the code to the whole page, or is it proprietary? You can use a service like http://pastie.org to paste it.

Comment: OK, i'll look at it and post any changes that are needed. One more question, there is no other CSS on that page? I didn't see a `link` element, but I just wanted to be sure. Also, try my edit to verify jQuery is loading properly by using the Google API version.

Answer (score 1):

You need a pound sign (`#`) to identify things by their `id` attribute, which uses the **[id selector](http://api.jquery.com/id-selector/)**. Try this instead:

```
$("#btEnviarAcesso")...
```

and:

```
... { $("#divLogin").slideToggle("slow"); });
```

Also, jQuery's show/hide functions don't affect the `visibility` attribute. Instead, use `"display: none"` for your element's style.

Comment: And a link to the docs: http://api.jquery.com/id-selector/.  In a nutshell, selectors in jQuery look a lot like css selectors.

Answer (score 0):

if you are using ID in  your html, use # in the query name:

```
$("#btEnviarAcesso").click(function () { $("#divLogin").slideToggle("slow"); });
```

Answer (score 0):

Your selector is no good, `btEnviarAcesso` is not an element. It probably needs to be `#btEnviarAcesso` if it is an `id` or a `.btEnviarAcesso` if it is a class.